# Homepage url redirect when logged in users type it in

Tags: php, wordpress

I want users for my site to be redirected when they are logged in. Example: Homepage for logged out users is www.test.com and when they are logged in i want them to be redirected to a different URL when they go to www.test.com, is there any way i can achieve this with some code?

Comment: You need to learn PHP Sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is using login_redirect hook
if you want to set redirect url role wise then use below code please.

Open theme functions.php file
Copy and paste the following code:
Please modify code as per your role wise.

```
function rl_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

        if ( in_array( 'author', $user->roles ) ) {
            // enter url which you link redirect for author role users. default is home page.
            return home_url();
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
} 
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'rl_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

if you want to set redirect url for all users then use below code please.

```
function rl_user_default_page() {
  return '/new-page-url';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'rl_user_default_page');
```